# C function in an objective-C class

Tags: objective-c, c, oop

If I create a C style function in an objective C class, will the function be a class level method? Or an instance method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It ignores the obj-c scope, and still uses the standard c style scoping.  so a function is generally global or static to the file.

Answer (score 3):

If you create a C function in Objective-C, it will not have any relationship to a particular class. That is, it will be in the global namespace. An example of this from the SDK is `NSLog(...)`.

Comment: @Alexsander: Thanks for the edit. Not sure if *in the global namespace* improved understandability for newbies!

Answer (score 0):

You can't attach C functions to an Objective-C class. If you want a "function" attached to a class, you have to declare it as a class method. Or you can declare the function outside of the class.

Comment: Note that Objective-C compilers do accept C functions to be declared or defined ‘inside’ an Objective-C class, i.e., inside an `@interface` or an `@implementation` block.